# How to add two logger files in .net core using LoggerFactory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } 

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {   
        loggerFactory.AddFile(logFilePath1);
        services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(loggerFactory);

        loggerFactory.AddFile(logFilePath2);
        services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(loggerFactory);
    }
}
```

With in the `startup.cs` class, I create two loggers . Since it has two loggers  how can I set the Ilogger data in the controller? can it do using normal way? Or is there any different way to pass logger filename when logged within the controller?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that would help us better understand what you are asking. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so you want to have two different loggers in a single controller and you want these two loggers to log to different files. The .NET Core logging does not have good support for this scenario so it requires a bit of hacking to achieve this. Whenever I find myself in a situation where I get a a lot of resistance from the framework I'm using I reconsider if what I'm trying to do is good idea and if it is whether I should use another framework so you might want to do the same. With that in mind here is a way to achieve what you want.

Loggers can be identified by a category. In your case you want a single controller to have two different loggers so you have to use `ILoggerFactory` to create the loggers (you could use the generic `ILogger<T>` interface but it becomes a bit weird because you need two different types for `T`):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger logger1;
    private readonly ILogger logger2;

    public Controller1(ILoggerFactor loggerFactory)
    {
        logger1 = loggerFactory.Create("Logger1");
        logger2 = loggerFactory.Create("Logger2");
    }
}
```

The categories of the loggers are `Logger1` and `Logger2`.

Each logger will by default log to all the configured providers. You want a logger with one category to log to one provider and a logger with another category to log to another provider.

While you can create filters that are based on category, provider and log level the problem is that you want to use the same provider for both categories. Providers are identified by their type so you cannot create a rule that targets a specific instance of a provider. If you create a rule for the file provider it will affect **all** configured file providers.

So this is where the hacking starts: You have to create your own provider types that are linked to the files to be able to filter on each file.

.NET Core does not have support for logging to files so you need a third party provider. You have not specified which provider you use so for this example I will use the Serilog file sink together with the Serilog provider that allows you to plug a Serilog logger into the .NET Core logging framework.

To be able to filter on provider you have to create your own provider. Luckily, that is easily done by deriving from the `SerilogLoggerProvider`:

```
class SerilogLoggerProvider1 : SerilogLoggerProvider
{
    public SerilogLoggerProvider1(Serilog.ILogger logger) : base(logger) { }
}

class SerilogLoggerProvider2 : SerilogLoggerProvider
{
    public SerilogLoggerProvider2(Serilog.ILogger logger) : base(logger) { }
}
```

These two providers does not add any functionality but allows you to create filter that targets a specific provider.

Next step is crating two different Serilog loggers that log to different files:

```
var loggerConfiguration1 = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("...\1.log");
var loggerConfiguration2 = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("...\2.log");
var logger1 = loggerConfiguration1.CreateLogger();
var logger2 = loggerConfiguration2.CreateLogger();
```

You configure your logging in `Main` by calling the extension method `.ConfigureLogging`:

```
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, loggingBuilder) =>
    {
        loggingBuilder
            .AddProvider(new SerilogLoggerProvider1(logger1))
            .AddFilter("Logger1", LogLevel.None)
            .AddFilter<SerilogLoggerProvider1>("Logger1", LogLevel.Information)
            .AddProvider(new SerilogLoggerProvider2(logger2))
            .AddFilter("Logger2", LogLevel.None)
            .AddFilter<SerilogLoggerProvider2>("Logger2", LogLevel.Information);
    })
```

Each provider (which is associated with a specific file) are added and then two filters are configured for each provider. I find the filter evaluation rules hard to reason about but the two filters added - one with `LogLevel.None` and another with `LogLevel.Information` - actually achieves the desired result of ensuring that log messages for the two different categories are routed correctly to the two different providers. If a third provider is added it will not be affected by these filters and messages from both categories will be logged by the third provider.

Comment: Hey @Martin, I think you got the question wrong. OP wants a way to store logs configured for two different files.

Comment: @Manoz: I agree that it is easy to get the question wrong. When I read _But how can I set the Ilogger data in the controller?_ I interpret this as a question on how to get an `ILogger` instance in the controller. I have to admit that I don't understand what you mean by _store logs configured for two different files._ and frankly I'm surprised that you seem to be so sure on how to interpret the original question which apparently can be interpreted in multiple ways.

Comment: Martin, It is my perception when I saw OP has registered two file paths in `startup.cs`. Probably this is what confused me.

Comment: @Manoz: You have to apply some guesswork to answer this question and my guess is certainly no better than yours. I hope the asker will clarify.

Comment: *“You have to apply some guesswork to answer this question”* – That sounds like the perfect reason to close-vote this question as unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin for your explanation. Actually i need to know the way of configure 2 logger files in same project. One controller will serve for one logger. and another controller will serve for different logger

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Using Serilog how can we logged data to two logger files when it has only one controller rather than using two controllers ? And also i have some issue in the point of logged messages. ex : logger.LogInformation("Hello, world!"); In here how do we pass which logger we wants to write data when we have 2 loggers in same controller ?

Comment: @OshiniGunarwardena: I have now made a third major edit of my question based on your comments which suggest that your question wasn't easy to understand in the first place. Hopefully you can take this as constructive feedback should you decide to ask another question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MartinLiversage this question is from quite a while ago but is exactly what I need.  Do you know then how to leverage these with dependency injection?

Comment: @drewid `ILoggerFactory` is being injected into the constructor of the controller using dependency injection so how _leverage_? If you want to hide the "ugliness" of creating two special loggers that are strongly linked to the configuration behind DI you can do that but DI in .NET relies on the type of the service being injected and two different `ILogger` services are still just `ILogger`. I guess you could declare `class Logger1 {}` outside a namespace and then inject `ILogger<Logger1>`? I haven't tried myself. Or perhaps use marker interfaces and inject using a factory (`IServiceProvider`).

Answer (score 0):

I created an aggregate logger for this purpose.

```
public class AggregateLogger : ILogger
{
    ILogger[] Loggers { get; set; }

    public AggregateLogger(params ILogger[] loggers) 
    {
        Loggers = loggers;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        List<IDisposable> disposables = new List<IDisposable>();
        
        foreach(var log in Loggers) 
            disposables.Add(log.BeginScope(state));

        Disposer disposer = new Disposer(disposables);
        return disposer;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return Loggers.Any(o => o.IsEnabled(logLevel));
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        foreach(var log in Loggers)
            log.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
    }
}

public class Disposer : IDisposable
{
    List<IDisposable> _disposables;

    public Disposer(List<IDisposable> disposables) 
    {
        _disposables = disposables;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var obj in _disposables)
            obj.Dispose();
    }
}
```