# NLog 2 files logging will log same info in both files

Tags: c#, nlog

So I have a rather simple problem, but seems like I am missing something. I have a WPF application ( .NET Core 5.0 ).

I am trying to use 2 files for logging, but whenever I retrieve one logger and write a message, I get the same log in both files.

Here is my code.

```
        private void SetupLogger()
        {
            // Step 1. Create configuration object 
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

            // Step 2. Create targets
            var firstTarget = new FileTarget()
            {
                Name = "FirstLogger",
                FileName = Path.Combine(basePath, "log1.txt"),
                Layout = "${longdate} ${level} ${message}  ${exception}"
            };

            var secondTarget = new FileTarget()
            {
                Name = "SecondLogger",
                FileName = Path.Combine(basePath, "log2.txt"),
                Layout = "${longdate} ${level} ${message}"
            };
            config.AddTarget("FirstLogger", firstTarget );
            config.AddTarget("SecondLogger", secondTarget );


            var ruleInfo1 = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, firstTarget );
            var ruleInfo2= new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, secondTarget );

            // Step 3. Define rules
            config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleInfo1); 
            config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleInfo2); 

            // Step 4. Activate the configuration
            LogManager.Configuration = config;

            // Example usage
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("FirstLogger");
            logger.Info("App starting...");
        }
```

In an other file I have a second log

```
        public void Start()
        {
            //initialize app
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("FirstLogger");
            logger.Info("App finished initializing...");
        }
```

Now what I see both logs in both files.

[image]

[image]

LE: I've tried this and it still logs to both files.

```
  var ruleInfo1 = new LoggingRule("FirstLogger", LogLevel.Trace, firstTarget )
            {
                Final = true
            };           
            var ruleInfo2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, secondTarget );

  config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleInfo1); 
            config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleInfo2);
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I have a "general log file" that logs important information. Now I am trying to add an other logger for some more specific information ( I want to log user actions and times ). I know I can just have one file with everything, but for me it makes more sense to have 2 files. In 2 words, one is a general log file for the hole app, one will be a log file for "user actions logging"

Comment: Specialized `LoggingRule` should be first in the list and have a filter different from `"*"`, for instance `new LoggingRule("FirstLogger",...)`, and also have property `Final` set to true. When you set all this up then the other logger with filter `"*"` will not be called.

Comment: Check my edit. I've found a solution. Would be to let me important logger low level to be Info. That way I could use trace/debug for my user interaction logging. This could work, but I was hoping I could log every level in both files, just by selecting a different logger from LogManager.

Comment: I put my suggestions to your method `SetupLogger` and called it, and the text "App starting" appeared only in the file log1.txt. It is not clear to me what do you mean by "I've tried this and it still logs to both files".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging-rules with wildcard `*` for the Logger-name will match all loggers:

```
// Step 3. Define rules
var ruleInfo1 = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, firstTarget );
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleInfo1);
var ruleInfo2 = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, secondTarget );
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleInfo2);
```

Maybe change into this:

```
// Step 3. Define rules
var ruleErrors = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Warn, firstTarget );
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleErrors);
var ruleUsers = new LoggingRule("UserLog", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, firstTarget );
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleUsers);
var ruleAll = new LoggingRule("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, secondTarget );
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleAll);
```

Now the 3 rules will ensure:

- **ruleErrors** - Will redirect warnings/errors into firstTarget (Filter on LogLevel)
- **ruleUsers** - Will redirect events written to `LogManager.GetLogger("UserLog")` into firstTarget (Filter on Logger-name)
- **ruleAll** - Will redirect all events to secondTarget (Without any filter)

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

Comment: Thank you, will try this today and accept if it works, looks like something I need.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.

The only difference between the two loggers is an exception.

You're not throwing any exceptions, and thus none will be logged.

Comment: Then let me iterate my question. Is there a way I can log same type of logs Info ( for example ) but chose in which file it should be logged?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740406/how-to-add-two-logger-files-in-net-core-using-loggerfactory Perhaps this could help?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, it looks like some overhead for what I want to achieve, but nevertheless it's a solution.